# Software & Updates "Settings" button missing

Tags: system-settings

The "Settings" button has disappeared from Software & Updates and it's no longer found under System Settings. If I run the Software Updater from the Dash it tells me that the Software on this computer is up to date. If I press OK it closes. There is no "Settings" option. I can't figure out how to get into Ubuntu Software, Other Software, Updates, Authentication or Additional Drivers. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.01 64 bit. While searching for a solution, I found the recommendation that I remove and reinstall the Unity Control Centre, but that hasn't helped. I am an Administrator, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I found the answer: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
This gave me the following:

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apturl apturl-common nautilus-share software-properties-gtk ubuntu-desktop

I have no idea how these got deleted, but they're back now.

Comment: software-properties-gtk should be enough, I think.

Comment: `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk`. I don't think this was deleted - it is missing by design in latest ubuntus.

Answer (score 2):

if setting is missing first check for gnome by

```
$ gnome-control-center
```

if it shows

> bash: gnome-control-center: command not found

then run command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

for "software and updates setting" missing run command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

you are Done.